# What is meaning of PE section field bit value IMAGE_SCN_MEM_SHARED?

Tags: win32-process

In a PE/COFF format file (for example, a Windows executable) in the section headers there is a field called Characteristics which has a bit mask value of IMAGE_SCN_MEM_SHARED (0x10000000) which is described by the spec as "The section can be shared in memory." What does this mean? Shared with what?

Also, as long as we are on this topic, what is the difference between the IMAGE_SCN_MEM_EXECUTE setting and the IMAGE_SCN_CNT_CODE setting?

Do the read / write settings result in flags being set on the memory to make readable/writable?

Answer (score 1):

That means this section memory can be shared with another process instance of the same image.